# Python min(x,y) in case of x/y/both is None

Tags: python

I would like to perform the following:

```
min_xy=min(x,y)
```

x/y/both of them may be None.
If I filter the None values in this way:

```
min_xy=min(filter(None,(x,y)))
```

I may get this assertion if x&y are both None.

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Is there an elegant way to get the little number if only one of them is None, and get None if both of them are?

Comment: ***little** number if only one of them is None* - it would not make much sense in context of the sequence of only 2 items. If one of them is None, then the remaining item is the only value (no need to find minimum). Otherwise, you should elaborate whether you are implying more than 2 item sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
min_xy = None if all(n is None for n in (x, y)) else min(filter(None,(x,y)))
```

You can also turn it into a `function`:

```
def min_xy(x, y):
    if all(n is None for n in (x, y)):
        return None
    else:
        return min(filter(None,(x,y)))
```

or a `lambda`:

```
min_xy = lambda x, y: None if all(n is None for n in (x, y)) else min(filter(None,(x,y)))
```

---

**Tests:**

```
print(min_xy(1, None))      # 1
print(min_xy(1, 2))         # 1
print(min_xy(None, 1))      # 1
print(min_xy(None, None))   # None
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since Python 3.4, `min` got updated to accept a default argument in case the iterable provided is empty. This allows for an elegant one-liner:

```
min_xy = min(filter(None, (x, y)), default=None)
```

- From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

  > *The default argument specifies an object to return if the provided iterable is empty. If the iterable is empty and default is not provided, a ValueError is raised.*

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of keeping things readable, I'd suggest:

```
def coalescing_min(*args):
    args = [i for i in args if i is not None]
    if args:
        return min(args)
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: if you want things to be readable, I believe you should add a return None in the end. :)

Comment: That's implied and would just clutter things up… :)

Comment: @deceze, according to style guides PEP8, *Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable)*. So, adding *return at the end of the function* is a good and recommended style manner

Comment: I like this answer the most actually. +1.

Comment: I like this answer the most too, but the non-return in the end blocks me.

Comment: Oh guys, stop with the nitpicks, How about `return min(args) if args else None`

Comment: OK, fiiiiiiine… ;)

Comment: FWIW, I think it looks better without the else.

Comment: I need to upvote these comments, sorry. Even though we can't blame someone for the `else` statement. :P

Comment: actually, since Python 3.4, `min` can have a default argument in case the iterable is empty! [Take a look!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = None, 1

min_xy = next(filter(lambda __: __ is not None, (x, y)), None) if any(map(lambda __: __ is None, (x, y))) else min(x, y)

print(min_xy)
```

Comment: This returns None if any of the numbers are None, but OP wants `Is there an elegant way to get the little number if only one of them is None, and get None if both of them are?`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_min(arr):
    mini = None
    for ar in arr:
        if ar is not None:
            mini = ar
            mini = min(ar,mini)
    return mini
```

It takes the argument as a list of any number of elements and returns the minimum. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
def nmin(*args):
    try:
        return min(x for x in args if x is not None)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```